# Obtaining differences between MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Today i need get the differences in two tables together its outcome, this is my scenario.

[image]

The desired result I need is the following:

[image]

I tryed the following SQL, but i cant get the desired result above:

```
SELECT
    Billings_Returns.billingreturn_id,
    Billings_Returns.billin_id,
    (Billings_Returns.billingreturn_total - Billings_Bills.billingbill_total) AS billingreturn_total
FROM Billings_Returns
LEFT JOIN Billings_Bills USING (billing_id)
```

Comment: For 3rd row and 4th rows billingreturntotal should be -30,-25 right?

Comment: What output does your query produce?

Comment: @Teja The 3rd row `billingreturn_total` value is `-25` and 4th is `5`, It is because they get the difference the next row.

Comment: Example: 3th row `75 - 100` and 4th row `80 - 75`

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank to @Teja, Solved the query:

```
SET @total=0;
SET @billingid=0;
SELECT billingreturn_id,
       billing_id,
       IF(billing_id = @billingid, (billingreturn_total + (@total * -1)), billingreturn_total) AS billingreturn_total, @total:=billingreturn_total AS curr_quote, @billingid:=billing_id AS curr_billingid
FROM
 (    SELECT
            billings_Returns.billingreturn_id,
            billings_Returns.billing_id,
            ( billings_returns.billingreturn_total -  
              billings_bills.billingbill_total
            ) AS billingreturn_total
      FROM billings_returns
      INNER JOIN 
           billings_Bills
        USING (billing_id)
) billings_returns;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT billingreturn_id,
       billing_id,
       - LAG( billingreturn_total, 1 ) OVER ( PARTITION BY billing_id ORDER BY billingreturn_id ) + billingreturn_total AS billingreturn_total
  FROM
     (    SELECT
                Billings_Returns.billingreturn_id,
                Billings_Returns.billing_id,
                ( Billings_Returns.billingreturn_total -  
                  Billings_Bills.billingbill_total
                ) AS billingreturn_total
          FROM Billings_Returns
         INNER JOIN 
               Billings_Bills U
            USING (billing_id); 
    ) Z;
```

The above query will produce the below output :

```
billingreturn_id | billingid | billingreturn_total
1                | 1         | -30
2                | 2         | -5
3                | 2         | -25
4                | 2         | 5
```

Comment: Please take a look to the desired result image above:  [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2eqo.png)

Comment: I'm getting 2 errors in the query syntax, Lines 3 and 15. `MySQL Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax `

Comment: I understood the problem.. LAG function doesnt work in mysql.. Let me write a different query that suits for mysql